# liferay portal: generate database not working

Tags: liferay

I've created a portal-ext.properties and added:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.default.url=x
jdbc.default.username=y
jdbc.default.password=z
schema.run.enabled=true
schema.run.minimal=true
```

And I've added my ojdbc5.jar to lib/ext.

However when I run my startup.bat the database isn't being generated?
Does anyone know why this is occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that the database is up and running.  Can you log into Oracle using SQL*Plus or some other client using the credentials you've provided?  If you can't, Liferay won't be able to either.

Comment: I tested the connection before starting, but the database crashed after that.

Comment: Any log messages to help understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using lifery's Data Migration feature? You can start your server with default HSQL script and then try to migrate (which can automatically create tables as well).

Go to Control Panel->Server Administration.
- Enter the values in section Migrate from One DB to another and click execute.